# How to write an application page it do the function of OfficeExportPage and UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, performancepoint

We deployed **BI reports** using **performance point services** to SharePoint BI site.

When user try to **Export to Excel**, the page redirects to `OfficeExportPage.aspx` and ask for authentication for **anonymous user**, this page is responsible for converting the report to excel and download to the user.

**Queries:**

- How to write an application page for it do the function of OfficeExportPage ?
- and deploy to this page to `_layouts` folder and give access permissions to  anonymous users to enable them to download the report into excel.
- How to Use the `UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase` class when creating this SharePoint Application Page?